# How to increase Chrome performance while working on resource-heavy Google Sheets?

Tags: google-chrome, google-spreadsheets

I'm working on a spreadsheet which is full of data and formulas, and I wondered if there is anything I can do to increase the performance of Chrome besides switching to Excel?

My device has 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7 and 16 GB RAM so I guess it's not a hardware problem.

P.S. I just added another formula and G Sheets stopped loading at all.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is no other solution than to simplify the spreadsheet.
If the spreadsheet is very complex, Excel will also be slow, although perhaps
faster than Google Sheets because it executes on the desktop and not inside
a browser.

There are articles to be found for doing that. For example:
[Slow Google Sheets? Here are 27 Ideas to Try Today](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/slow-google-sheets/).

I reproduce the list from the above article, but for details see the article
itself.

> 1. How to recognize slow Google Sheets
> 2. Know the size limits of Google Sheets
> 3. Measure a Google Sheet’s size
> 4. Measure a Google Sheet’s calculation speed
> 5. Delete un-used cells
> 6. Convert formulas to static values wherever possible
> 7. Use closed range references
> 8. Remove volatile functions or use with caution
> 9. Vlookup strategies
> 10. Index-Match strategies
> 11. Query function strategies
> 12. Array Formula strategies
> 13. Import Formula strategies
> 14. Google Finance function strategies
> 15. Use IF statements to manage formula calls
> 16. Manage expensive formulas with a control switch
> 17. Use Filter, Unique and Array_Constrain functions to create smaller helper tables
> 18. Avoid long calculation chains
> 19. Reference data on the same Sheet
> 20. Use helper columns
> 21. Split your slow Google Sheet into separate Sheets
> 22. Use Conditional Formatting sparingly
> 23. Leverage the power of Apps Script
> 24. Use custom formulas sparingly
> 25. Other troubleshooting tips for slow Google Sheets
> 26. Understand changes in the cloud can take time to propagate
> 27. Know when it’s time to move to a database

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know what to do on Windows, but on the Mac, switching to Safari might actually help. No kidding - from my experience, on complex Google Sheets, Safari will be about twice as fast as Chrome.